# How to bind app's view-model to custom element using a promise?

Tags: aurelia

I would like to bind a value present in my app.js view-model to a custom element, but I can't seem to get `bind` to work properly when the value of `images` is set from a ***Promise***.

`app.js`:

```
@inject(Api)
export class App {
    constructor(api) {
        this.api = api;
    }

    . . .

    activate() {
        this.api.mockGet('gallery').then((images) => this.images = images);
    }
}
```

My custom element, as referenced in `app.html`:

```
<featured-image images.bind="images"></featured-image>
```

My custom element's view-model, `featured-image.js`:

```
import {containerless, bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';

@containerless
export class FeaturedImage {
    @bindable images = null;

    attached() {
        console.log(this.images);
    }
}
```

`this.images` is always `undefined`. If I set `images` to a hard-coded array, it works as expected. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to return the promise in the `activate`:

```
activate() {
   return this.api.mockGet('gallery')
      .then((images) => this.images = images);
}
```

This ensures that your view will activate when the the promise has been completed. However, I think it should work even with no `return` because any changes in the array will propagate to all views that bind it. Perhaps another thing is causing the issue.

Comment: Very interesting. That works, but I'd like to understand why. Is there a reference in the docs?

Comment: Yes, there is. http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/framework/1.0.0-beta.1.1.4/doc/article/cheat-sheet/7 "Implement this hook if you want to perform custom logic just before your view-model is displayed. You can optionally return a promise to tell the router to wait to bind and attach the view until after you finish your work."

Comment: Derp - thank you very much for the help! I appreciate it.